# Remove Dots after Sub(sub)section and Paragraph

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

How can I remove the last dot after the Sub(sub)section and paragraph. This should be both in the TOC and in the Headers of the text.
It should look like this:

1.

1.1

1.1.1

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\let \savenumberline \numberline
\def \numberline#1{\savenumberline{#1.}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Blablabla}
\subsection{blabla}
\subsubsection{haha}
\paragraph{HaHa} ~\\
\end{document}
```

Maybe someone can help. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
% dotprob.tex  SE 590548
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{comment}
\let \savenumberline \numberline
\def \numberline#1{\savenumberline{#1.}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\end{comment}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Blablabla}
\subsection{blabla}
\subsubsection{haha}
\paragraph{HaHa} ~\\
\end{document}
```

The above just (re)sets the division number representations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

TOC:

Remove the redefinition of `\numberline` and add

```latex
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
```

for the dot after the section number.

Headers in text:

Replace `\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}` eg. by

```latex
\usepackage{scrextend}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\Ifstr{\thetitle}{\thesection}{.}{}\quad}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}% <- dot after section number in TOC
%\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\Ifstr{\thetitle}{\thesection}{.}{}\quad}% <- dot after section number in section header

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Blablabla}\label{sec:Bla}
In section~\ref{sec:Bla} there is a dot after the number in the heading and the ToC but not in the reference.
\subsection{blabla}
\subsubsection{haha}
\paragraph{HaHa} ~\\
\end{document}
```

[image]